# What are the Alternatives of One Arm Dumbbell Row?

Tags: dumbbells

I have recently started using from last one month. After getting up from beginner level, I am moving to alternatives of few exercise. I am asking this to know about One arm dumbbell row alternatives. Recently I asked one of Gym friend and he suggested me go through [this website of one arm](http://www.onearmdumbbellrow.com/) which looks me really helpful. Please suggest me some other alternatives you have tried.

Answer (score 1):

When you say alternatives, are you looking for exercises which also isolate one arm?  Or exercises that mimic that movement?

Since I'm not sure which one you're referring to, I'll list a few exercises that mimic the movement and I'll specify if you can do them with one arm or not.

- T-bar row
- Cable row
- Hammer grip seated row (Can be done with one arm)
- Hammer strength pull downs (Can be done with one arm)
- Bent over barbell row

Comment: It's a compound back exercise so literally any other back exercise would be suitable. There are a lot of options... http://www.exrx.net/Lists/ExList/BackWt.html

Comment: Disagree completely.  Just because it's a back exercise, that doesn't mean it's working the same muscles or can be done with one arm.  Reverse fly, hyperextensions, deadlift, etc. are all back exercises that don't relate to the exercise he said.

Comment: But those exercises don't. Deadlift, Hypers = Erector Spinae & Upper Legs; Reverse Fly = Delts only. Your answer is mostly correct. T-Bar, Cable, Hammer Seated, and Bent Over Rows are all compound back movements. Pull-downs target Lats only.

Answer (score 0):

The one-arm-dumbbell-row is a compound back exercise. It works out similar muscles to the barbell/pendlay row. http://www.exrx.net/WeightExercises/BackGeneral/DBBentOverRow.html

There are many isolation exercises for back (eg. Reverse Fly, Pull-over, Chins)  but for a compound back exercise look towards:

- Bent over/Pendlay Row
- T-bar
- Literally anything here under "General Back": http://www.exrx.net/Lists/ExList/BackWt.html#General